# Bootstrap Badge - Text Not Centered in Badge

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I can't figure out how to get my text to align with the middle of my icon. This is using Chrome. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/25232/).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label class="badge badge-secondary align-middle">
  <span class="pb-2">Should Be Centered</span>
  <i class="material-icons md-18">cancel</i>
</label>
```

Any suggestion is welcome!

Example image:

[image]

Comment: can you give a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Cancel button shows to me as text.

Comment: Can you try align-items-center class instead of align-middle class.

Comment: The JS fiddle works for me. Not sure why you're having an issue.

Comment: @theMayer It can't coz you haven't added material icons to your CSS.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - did you miss this line?  `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @theMayer It wasn't there in the fiddle mate... Check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfJWi.png

Comment: @PraveenKumar well that's odd... I guess that must be a bug with js fiddle... not sure why it doesn't show for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd want to put `align-middle` on the badge contents, instead of the `badge`...

```
  <label class="badge badge-secondary">
    <span class="pb-2 align-middle">Should Be Centered</span>
    <i class="material-icons md-18 align-middle">cancel</i>
  </label>
```

Demo with MD icon: https://www.codeply.com/go/TkAEvkUcXB

Comment: Thanks, this works. I just didn't try enough combinations.

Comment: Right! Bootstrap has utility classes! LoL. `:D` Forgot that.

Answer (score 9):

You can Bootstrap [Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) utilities to happen this.

```
<label class="badge badge-secondary d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
    <span>Should Be Centered</span>
    <i class="material-icons md-18">cancel</i>
</label>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ERgBww) example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this property too!

```
 span{
   vertical-align: super;
  }
```